# Filter out Git history for all items NOT present in current HEAD

Tags: git

I have a repo that I want to filter to remove the commit history for all files/directories that are NOT present in the current HEAD (even if they have already been deleted in prior commits). It would be nice to output the list of items that get filtered out as well for auditing.

I am attempting to collapse history to only items in the current HEAD.

I suspect this is a filter-branch or similar operation but not quite sure how to pull this off.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the repository does not involve any submodule.

1.Find all the files that are in `HEAD`, as Group 1.

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | sort -u
```

2.Find all the file that are in the ancestors of `HEAD`, as Group 2.

```
sort -u <(
    for commit in $(git log --pretty=%H $(git log --pretty=%P HEAD));do
        git ls-tree -r --name-only $commit
    done;
)
```

3.Find the files that are in Group 2 and not in Group 1.

```
diff -B <(git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | sort -u) <(
    sort -u <(
        for commit in $(git log --pretty=%H $(git log --pretty=%P HEAD));do
            git ls-tree -r --name-only $commit
        done;
    )
) | awk '/^>/{print "\""$2"\""}'
```

4.Combine these files in one line as `"path1" "path2" "path3"`

```
paths=$(
    diff -B <(git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | sort -u) <(
        sort -u <(
            for commit in $(git log --pretty=%H $(git log --pretty=%P HEAD));do
                git ls-tree -r --name-only $commit
            done;
        )
    ) | awk '/^>/{print "\""$2"\""}'
)
```

5.Remove these files from the history of `HEAD`.

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty -f --tree-filter 'rm -rf $paths'
```